# Determining damaged resistor value

Tags: resistors

I'm looking for help finding this resistor. I’m having trouble finding a comparable one. If I'm looking at it correctly it should be a 41.9 ohm resistor but the black line is confusing me. It's in a heater if that's any help.

[image]

Comment: Nice picture! I don't know the answer to your question but I wanted to complement you for presenting such a nice photo.

Comment: You did notice the blown MOV, right?

Comment: I noticed and have identified the varistor. The resistor does not have continuity anymore and needs to be replaced as well though :)

Comment: There's some out-of-focus text on the PCB next to the component.  Is that saying CP1 and CP2?  Are those labeling the connectors instead?  Is there any text or symbology visible from another angle that could help confirm it's a resistor? Maybe the text that's partly blocked by the capacitor.  (An answer proposes it could be an inductor.)

Comment: It says RY1 for the part description which is partially hidden by the cap

Answer (score 17):

Possibly a 0.47Ω fusible resistor. You should replace it with a similar fusible resistor for continued protection.

Looks like the nearby varistor also bought the farm, and that also should be replaced with a similar size and rating of varistor for continued protection.

If the varistor is after the resistor, that may be all that is wrong with the product (which is not always the case, often problems run much deeper).

Answer (score 11):

The resistor bands are clearly yellow-purple-silver-gold-black.

Purple band can be identified even if it is mostly but not completely charred. Since the intention was to replace it anyway, you could have taken it off to see the colours better.

So it is not a 41.9 ohms, but 0.47 ohms.

Silver means a multiplier of 0.01.

Gold means a tolerance of 5%

And what the extra black band resembles is anyone's guess, but it means it's special.

It might mean temperature coefficient, failure rate, fusible resistor, or anything manufacturer specific.

Please understand that if you don't replace the resistor with the same type of resistor, the device can become a fire or shock hazard, just so to know that by fixing it yourself, you take the responsibility too.

Having said that, it is very likely to be a fusible resistor. It is likely there to protect from failed MOVs, as seen from the picture. MOVs tend to fail short or start conducting more and more current when they have been suppressing surges over time.

Which why it is extremely important that the resistor is of the correct type for the job.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I can’t take it off as it’s for a job and I need to determine if I can find a replacement for it and quote the customer before I start ripping apart their heater hence why I’m posting here as I need to ensure that I find the right replacement and I’m sure that it is the right replacement